# Android App: How to autofill the edit text field with received OTP?

Tags: android, sms, one-time-password

I have used Broadcast receiver to read OTP from received sms and i have extracted it. I have also displayed the OTP using Toast. But i don't want user to memorize and enter the OTP, I want to populate the text field with that OTP. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Write a total of two broadcast listeners. One listener in the activity which has the `EditText` to populate the value into it.

```
editField.setText(otp);
```

One more listener outside the activity which can save the value temporarily. If the user happens to be outside the activity when broadcast is received then you can just check this value in `onResume()` and populate the field at that time.

Comment: i am dealing with broadcast receivers for the first time..could you please rovide detailed solution?

Comment: Register broadcast receiver when activity is started and unregister when the activity is closed. This ensures that the broadcast receiver code will only work when activity is running. So if otp is received when acitivty is running the listener will read it and populate the value. If activity is closed when sms comes then broadcast receiver registered in service will receive it and can write in sharedPreferences. When the activity is started again then you can read the value from sharedPreference and then populate the field. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html